# append item to select box with jquery while escaping quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, escaping, quotes

I'm adding options to a select box as follows:

```
x.append("<option value="+option_to_add+">"+option_to_add+"</option>");
```

where "option_to_add" can be any value a user has entered.
Of course, a problem arises when adding options that have single or double quotes in them.

Is there a way to escape these values correctly before appending them to a select list

e.g. this will be a problem

user types: `he"llo`
my code will try to append this as : `<option value="he"llo"/>` which crashes the html/js

Comment: `escape(option_to_add);` should work I should think

Comment: @Val: `escape` doesn’t do what you think it does in JavaScript. You must be thinking of PHP.

Comment: @mathias it does encode the value, and u can decode it on server side

Answer (score 7):

I found a native jQuery way to handle this correctly:

```
.append($("<option></option>").attr("value",option_to_add).text(option_to_add));
```

Comment: +1 Yes this! jQuery's .text() is an easy to use, UTF-8 safe way that won't mess up with Unicode characters when reading and writing escaped values from form fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could you the Javascript replace function to escape or remove the quotes...
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to escape the `"` characters, like this: `\"`

This can be automated as follows:

```
'foo"bar"baz'.replace(/"/g, '\\"'); // 'foo\"bar\"baz'
```

You’ll only need to do this for the `value` attribute of the `<option>` element, so the full code snippet would be:

```
x.append('<option value="' + option_to_add.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '">' + option_to_add + '</option>');
```